# Java Embedded Application - What is needed on the device

Tags: java, linux, embedded, java-me

I am trying to deploy a Java application on an embedded device (just a simple "Hello World" would be a good start).

On my host machine (Linux x64) I have downloaded the Java ME tool, and together with the JDK I have created the so called Java IMlet class, the Jar and the JAD files, as pointed out in the [guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.3/sdk-dev-guide/java-me-embedded-applications.htm#MESDD145).

The tutorial shows at the end how to run the example by emulating the embedded system, but I want to run the application **on** the embedded system.

My question is, now that I have created all the files described in the guide above (Jar,Jad,Manifest,.Class), what are the minimal requirements I need to have on my target embedded system (ARM Linux) in order to run the application? And how to run it? Do I need the JVM, or a JRE installed on the embedded device?

Sorry if the questions seem really basic, but I am a total beginner with Java (know well C++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched on downloading the [JRE headless for ARM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/javaseembedded7u75-2601858.html) (which has a footprint of about 35-40 MB, and is acceptable to me).

This way I am building the application on my host Linux x64, and then via ssh I send the JRE plus the compiled *.class file to my embedded system. To run I then just use the "java" command under the bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

For C/C++, the executable contains op-codes, which can directly run on underlying CPU. So, when C/C++ code is build and executable is created for x86, the op-codes in would be of x86 machine, and when cross-compiled for ARM, the op-codes would be of ARM.

But for Java, the executable always contains Java specific op-codes (byte-codes), which needs an interpreter to decode and execute on underlying CPU.
So, if you want to run any Java output file, ensure that JRE or JDK is available on the target.

Hope it helps.